# Password is not encrypted in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, password-encryption

I have this code in my controller file:

```
       $data = array(
                    'username' => $this->input->post('txt_username'),
                    'password'=>$this->input->post('txt_password')
     );

            $encriptKey = 'super-secret-key';
            $encrypted_string = $this->encrypt->encode($password, $encriptKey);

               if ($this->account_model->insertUser($data,$encrypted_string))
             { 
                $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','successfully registered!');
}
```

and i have this code in my model file:

```
function insertUser($data,$encrypted_string)
    {
          return $this->db->insert('user', $data,$encrypted_string);
    }
```

The password is not encrypted. I have initialized encryption class. struck here!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not placed the encrypted password into the `$data` array.

As far as I know the db->insert only accepts 2 params, table and $data array

So try putting the encrypted password into the $data array

```
$encriptKey = 'super-secret-key';

$data = array('username' => $this->input->post('txt_username'),
              'password' => $this->encrypt->encode($this->input->post('txt_password'), $encriptKey)
             );

if ($this->account_model->insertUser($data)) { 
    $this->session->set_flashdata('msg','successfully registered!');
}
```

And

```
function insertUser($data)
{
    return $this->db->insert('user', $data);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

But why are you saving the plain POST password in you data array? I assume you want to insert an encrypted password into your database, then try something like that:

```
$data = array(
                'username' => $this->input->post('txt_username'),
                'password'=>$this->encrypt->encode($password, $encriptKey);
 );
```

Now you can insert $data, and you have an encrypted password

Comment: this too is helpful but the answer by @RiggsFolly is more illustrated. thanks